# Как работает базово-индексная адресация?

Tags: c, ассемблер, x86

```
addw (%edx,%ecx,4), %ax # базово-индексная адресация
                        # %edx - базовый регистр, адрес массива Numbers,
                        # %ecx - счетчик по элементам, 4 — т. к.
                        # в call-S был объявлен как массив int
```

Как работает эта адресация? Точнее нет, как работает она, я понимаю, а вот 4 для чего и за что отвечает не понимаю.

Тип, просто потому что у нас дан массив интов, и чтобы попасть в следующий элемент надо прибавить 4? Или что мы с ней вообще делаем?

Comment: Интересная нотация у вашего ассемблера, так действительно выглядит не понятно. В большинстве ассемблеров инструкция была бы записана как `addw [edx+ecx*4], ax` Так конечно гораздо понятнее, что 4 это множитель для счетчика элементов массива, так как сдвигаться надо по 4 байта

Comment: @Mike, только наоборот, `addw ax, [edx+ecx*4]`...

Comment: @Fat-Zer А, да, точно, в этой дурацкой нотации еще и операнды не в той последовательности :)

Comment: @Mike, а мне как раз последовательность в AT&T нравится больше: читается естественно: `mov %ax, %bx` : `перемести %ax в %bx`... но синтаксис адресации, действительно вырвиглазный... и это ещё в примере смещения нет: `inc -0x20(%edx,%ecx,4)`...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, а мне, наоборот, адресация в AT&T нравится больше. Вот [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9958480/8086115) хорошо показан ужас Intel синтакиса по сравнению с AT&T.

Comment: @eanmos, я присоединюсь к смущению первого комментатора по ссылке...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, ну да, примеры высосаны из пальца, но ведь в некоторых случаях `DWORD` и `PTR` использовать необходимо. Выглядит ужасно, по-моему. В AT&T такого нету. Хотя опять же, дело вкуса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такая адресация в мануалах Intel описывается следующим образом:

> **Base + (Index × Scale) + Displacement** — Using all addressing components together allows efficient indexing of a two-dimensional
> array when the elements of the array are 2, 4, or 8 bytes in size.

В синтаксисе языка ассемблера Intel записывается точно также как в мануале:

```
[Base + Index * Scale + Displacement]
```

В вашем случае было бы

```
addw AX, [EDX + ECX * 4 + 0]
```

Синтаксис языка ассемблера AT&T сильно отличается от синтаксиса Intel и там такой режим адресации можно записать следующим образом:

```
displacement(base, index, scale)
```

Соответственно, в вашем случае:

```
addw (%edx, %ecx, 4), %ax
      ^~~~  ^~~~  ^ 
      |     |     +-- scale
      |     +-- index
      +-- base
```

#### Как это используется

Допустим, у нас есть массив чисел типа `int32_t` (4 байта) из 32-х элементов:

```
int32_t array[32];
```

Тогда чтобы обратиться в пятому элементу массива мы можем использовать следующий режим адресации:

```
(array, 5, 4)
 ^~~~   ^  ^
 |      |  +-- размер элементов массива
 |      +-- индекс нужного элемента
 +-- адрес самого массива
```

Это работает, потому что, когда мы умножаем индекс элемента на его размер, то получаем смещение от начала массива, по которому расположен этот элемент. А когда мы прибавим к адресу массива это смещение, то получим адрес самого элемента.

---

Хотя, для обращения к элементам одномерных статических массивов документация Intel рекомендует использовать **(Index × Scale) + Displacement**, что и делают компиляторы:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

const int32_t array[32] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

int
main(void)
{    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 32; ++i)
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
}
```

Обращение к элементам массива компилятор транслирует в следующий код:

```
movl    array(,%rax,4), %eax
```

Comment: Боже, только сейчас увидела Ваш ответ, спасибо большое, всё стало на свои места теперь!